# jQuery return all Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can i get all the contents of the array outside the function?

```
 $.each(Basepath.Templates, function(i){
     templateArray = new Array({title: Basepath.Templates[i].Template.name, src: 'view/'+Basepath.Templates[i].Template.id, description: Basepath.Templates[i].Template.name});
});

console.log(templateArray); //contains only one array;
```

**Edit:**

this is the output i want

```
templateArray[
    {
        title: "one",
        src: "view/1",
        description: "Descrption 1"
    },
    {
        title: "two",
        src: "view/2",
        description: "Descrption 2"
    },
    {
        title: "one",
        src: "view/3",
        description: "Descrption 3"
    }
]
```

Comment: `templateArray = new Array` **of course it is one array** what is the question?

Comment: Anyway, it's **too localized**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `templateArray` in each iteration. Try [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) instead of `each()`:

```
var templateArray = $.map(Basepath.Templates, function(tpl, i){
    return {
        title: tpl.Template.name,
        src: 'view/'+tpl.Template.id,
        description: tpl.Template.name
    };
});
console.log(templateArray); // now is only one array, containing template objects;
```

Comment: thanks it works! it saves my project! :D

Comment: @gdoron: Will I? I didn't code `$(array).map(iterator).get()`.

Comment: No, you're right. I never used `map` this way.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting up the variable for the array before the `.each()` call and add to the array on each iteration.

```
var templateArray = [];
$.each(Basepath.Templates, function(i){
    templateArray.push({title: Basepath.Templates[i].Template.name, src: 'view/'+Basepath.Templates[i].Template.id, description: Basepath.Templates[i].Template.name});
});

console.log(templateArray); //should work
```

Comment: good catch noticing array was being overwritten.

Comment: i had set the variable before the function but it still return a single array..

thanks,